# Vim Format Text (Break line) at a fixed length intelligently

Tags: vim, format, idl, paragraph

I have acquired a huge codebase in which the previous developer(s) did not follow 80 characters length. I am trying to for a really long lines into multiple lines with continuation. This is a `IDL` language.

**Before**

```
test_function, variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, variabl6, variable7, vaiable8, variable9, variable10, ...
```

**After**

```
test_function, variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, $
    variable5, variable6, variable7, variable8, variable9,  $
    variable10
```

I have used `formatprg` and [par](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/) for formatting a paragraph. I am looking for a way so that it will break the line (intelligently) at about 80 characters at `comma` (and possibly add continuation ($) sign). It will be a huge time saving, as I do not have to break these 1000's of lines to 80 characters manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272247/5152421

Vim does this very easily.

```
gq{motion} % format the line that {motion} moves over
{Visual}gq % format the visually selected area
gqq        % format the current line
...
```

I'd suggest you check out `:help gq` and `:help gw`.

Also setting textwidth (`tw`) will give you auto line break when exceeded during typing. It is used in `gq` too, though if disabled `gq` breaks on window size or 79 depending on which comes first.

```
:set tw=80
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set it by formatting options, but this workaround could do the job

```
:%s/\%>68c \%<78c/ $\r/
```

It means substitute(`%s`) matched space () between columns 68 (`%>68c`) and 78 (`%<78c`) by space and `$` and line break (`\r`). 78 because of appending two characters at the end of the line.

[`:h \%c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25c)

---

There are also comments which would be nice to keep, so before you run first substitution, run this command

```
:%s/\(^\s\{-};\).*\%>68c\zs \%<78c/\r\1 /
```

It means substitute on lines which begins with `;` (and possibly some whitespaces before(`\s\{-}`)), start the match (`\zs`) after column 68 till 78, take the beginning of the line till `;` (`\(^\s\{-};\)`), and pass it (`\1`) after line break.

[`:h \s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs)
[`:h \{`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%7B-)
[`:h \zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs)
[`:h \(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28)